# Mod_rewrite on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use `mod_rewrite` on Amazon S3?

```
www.example.com/about.html -> mybucket.s3.amazon.com/index.html
www.example.com/welcome.html -> mybucket.s3.amazon.com/index.html
www.example.com/contact.html -> mybucket.s3.amazon.com/index.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can use *Error Document*.

[image]

Comment: Awesome !! a little explanation would be appreciated please

Answer (score 1):

The error document solution works on the surface, but if you check the actual response status header you'll see the page comes back as a 404. This is obviously not good.

I'm still looking for alternatives, for now I think I'll resort to using hashbangs.

Answer (score 0):

No.

But you can host it under a different sub-domain.
eg You can have

```
s.example.com/about.html 
s.example.com/welcome.html 
s.example.com/contact.html
```

and serve them directly from it. 
Better still is serving these files in cloudfront.
Here is how you get your own [subdomain in cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).

One question to you is. All these files are mostly static, not performance heavy and 
rarely visited. Hosting them in CDN looks bit overkill.